# Why this video won't play on iOS devices?

Tags: ios, video, h.264

http://films2.video.ru/preview/8/1/18356_oth1.mp4

It works well on mac, but does not on iPad & iPhone. Format is H.264, AAC, size is 720 × 544 - so it is below 720p that iPhone 4 can play. It's not playing in mobile safari too, so it is not my application problem. What can be wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out that playing video on iOS devices is not only about format, sizes and frame rate. There is also an "encoding profile", that should be for iPhone 4 up to level 3.1, for iPhone 4S up to level 4.1. My video had level 5.1, so this is the reason.

You can find out encoding profile for your video using VideoSpec http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/25921/videospec

Answer (score 0):

Some videos need to have a slightly different encoding before they will play on iOS.

There are a number of converters out there to try including a few free converters.

Handbrake: 
http://handbrake.fr/

MPEG Streamclip
http://www.squared5.com/

Quicktime Pro also has an Export>Movie to iPhone setting. 
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1311713